# How to update with SerializerMethodField in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a  field in my ModelSerializer which I've  set as SerializerMethodField to modify the get behaviour for the field. I could update the data before, now I can't. How can I solve this?

Initially, without using SerializerMethodField, I got data like this:

```
    {
        ...
        "members": [2,3],
        ...
    }
```

but I  added SerializerMethodField to modify the data, then update stopped working.

**models.py**

```
# Create your models here.
class Company(models.Model):
    members = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True), blank=True)
...
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model=Account
        fields='__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=False)
    members = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__' #('id', 'name', 'description', 'date_created', 'user', 'status', 'theme', 'members')

    def get_members(self, obj):
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(id__in=obj.members)
        return AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True).data
...
```

Comment: You need to use different serializer for update and create. This serializer works for get only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to use different serializers for update and create. This serializer works for get only.
2. Or, you can create a custom field. [Django Rest Framework How to update SerializerMethodField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475829/django-rest-framework-how-to-update-serializermethodfield)
3. Or, there can be other simpler hooks. If 'create' and 'update' worked as you wanted before modifiying `members`, then you can do as follow to get everything to default for create and update requests.

- Instead of using `SerializerMethodField`, override serializer representation.

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'date_created', 'user', 'status', 'theme', 'members', 'members_data')

    def to_representation(self, obj)
        ret = super().to_representation(obj)
        ret["members"] = AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True).data
        return ret
```

- Override the `__init__` method .
  .

```py
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            if self.context['request'].method in ['GET']:
                self.fields['members'] = SerializerMethodField()
        except KeyError:
            pass

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__' #('id', 'name', 'description', 'date_created', 'user', 'status', 'theme', 'members')

    def get_members(self, obj):
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(id__in=obj.members)
        return AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True).data
...
```

- Or, you can create different field for getting members.

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=False)
    members_data = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'date_created', 'user', 'status', 'theme', 'members', 'members_data')

    def get_members_data(self, obj):
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(id__in=obj.members)
        return AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True).data
...
```

Comment: Thanks, Sagar! :) Now another problem, when adding a new item, this comes out: **null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint Django** . What does this mean in my case? )

Comment: This is another problem. You cannot create/update nested relation(UserSerializer Here) directly.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I discovered the `to_representation` usage that allowed me to remove the `SerializerMethodField` I created, that broke update on dates fields.